# What does やの mean in 汚れやの匂いがする?

Tags: meaning, sentence

> 汚れやの匂いがする

I know the sentence means something along the lines of "smells like dirt". But I have no idea what the やの means.

The context is that it is talking about the natural forest concoction in the cauldron in Stardew Valley that the (old) wizard is mixing.

Edit: Picture of context、and I forgot が

[image]

Edit 2: I switched the language and got [image]

Comment: It's probably a typo, but [please paste the entire sentence](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2189/5010) rather than a fragment of a sentence.

Comment: @naruto I edited it, since I was missing a particle, but that's really the entire sentence as seen in the picture.

Comment: Thank you. Unless 汚れや is a noun that means something special in this game (which is unlikely), I must say it's a mere typo.

Comment: @VietNguyen How about switching to another language (from title menu) to uncover the mystery?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to your second screenshot, the mystery is solved - It's just a typo.

The translated sentence should be:

> 汚れや苔{こけ}の匂いがする...

That witch probably put the moss (or some sort of lichens) and some alchemical/magical materials to their cauldron, which is now source of the smell.

Answer (score 0):

これは本当にあなたが抜き取った正しい文章なのですか？

この文章は少し変に見えます。`〇〇や`と言うふうに付けるなら話の対象が２つであるはずです。

**例：**

汚れやホコリの匂いする

---

そしてそれ以前に「匂いする」と言う表現の仕方に少し違和感を感じます。
本来の正しい言い方なら「匂いがする」のハズです。

おそらく昔の言い方かなにかだと思われます。

（古い言い方なら〇〇の匂いあり。的な言い方をすると思いますが）

Comment: I mistakenly forgot to add a が if that helps you (and added a picture).

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure...  Is there were any shops or house that name is "汚れ"?
「〇〇や」is often used in 〇〇屋(shops name)